# Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to fix the syntax, I wanted to execute only one select statement based on user input ie @id

```
Create Procedure employee
    @id int,
    @year int
AS
    SELECT 
        CASE 
           WHEN @id = 1 
             THEN (select a.name, b.roles 
                   from employee a 
                   inner join department b on a.id = b.id
                   where b.years in (@year) 
                      or b.roles is not null) 
           ELSE 
              CASE 
                 WHEN @id = 2 
                   THEN (select a.name, b.dayoff 
                         from employee a 
                         inner join department b on a.id = b.id
                         where b.years in (@year) 
                            or b.dayoff is not null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you want `if`:

```
Create Procedure employee (
    @id int,
    @year int
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @id = 1
    BEGIN
        select a.name, b.roles
        from employee a join
             department b
             ON a.id = b.id
             where b.years IN (@year) OR b.roles IS NOT NULL  ) ;
    END
    ELSE if @id = 2 
    BEGIN 
        select a.name, b.dayoff
        from employee a join
             department b
             ON a.id = b.id
        where b.years IN (@year) OR b.dayoff IS NOT NULL  ) ;
    END
END;
```

I am not sure why you are using `in` with `@year`; this will only work if there is one value in `@year`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, but after replacing i still get incorrect syntax near THEN. am i missing something..?

Comment: @kdud . . . Ooops, SQL Server doesn't have a `THEN`.  I usually put any statement between `BEGIN` and `END`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line

```
 SELECT CASE WHEN @id = 1 THEN
```

To this

```
IF @id = 1 THEN
```

Cause you can't use `CASE` expression like this and it should be used within a query. With that your code block should look like

```
IF @id = 1 THEN

(select a.name, b.roles from employee a 
INNER JOIN department b ON a.id = b.id
where b.years IN (@year) 
OR b.roles IS NOT NULL  ) 

ELSE 

(select a.name, b.dayoff from employee a 
INNER JOIN department b ON a.id = b.id
where b.years IN (@year) 
OR b.dayoff IS NOT NULL  )
```